# DevExpress MVC Editors get value on Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress

I have a popupcontrol declared in my razor cshtml file as follow:

```
    @Html.DevExpress().PopupControl(settings =>
{
settings.Name = "popSendBackReview";
settings.HeaderText = "Send Review Back to Scheduler";
settings.AllowResize = false;
settings.ShowHeader = true;
settings.ShowOnPageLoad = false;
settings.AllowDragging = true;
settings.CloseAction = CloseAction.CloseButton;
settings.CloseOnEscape = false;
settings.Modal = true;
settings.PopupElementID = "popSendBackReview";
settings.AutoUpdatePosition = true;
settings.PopupHorizontalAlign = PopupHorizontalAlign.WindowCenter;
settings.PopupVerticalAlign = PopupVerticalAlign.WindowCenter;
settings.Height = 280;
settings.Width = 450;

settings.SetContent(() =>
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_SendBackReviewPanel");
});
}).GetHtml()
```

The partial view contains a memo box and button that calls an action:

```
@Html.DevExpress().Memo(settings =>
{
settings.Width = 300;
settings.Height = 150;
settings.Style.Add("margin-bottom", "10px");
settings.Name = "txtReviewComment";
settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;
settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.ErrorText = "A Review Comment is Required.";
settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.Text;
settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorTextPosition = ErrorTextPosition.Bottom;
settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.Display = Display.Dynamic;
settings.Properties.ValidationSettings.ValidationGroup = "Review";
}).GetHtml()

@Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
{
settings.Name = "btnSaveReview";
settings.Text = "Send Back for Scheduler Review";
settings.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
settings.ValidationGroup = "Review";
settings.RouteValues = new { Controller = "Matter", Action = "ResolveReview", Pass = false, Comment = Model.CommentText };
}).GetHtml()

@Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
{
settings.Name = "btnCancelReview";
settings.Text = "Cancel";
settings.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s,e) { popSendBackReview.Hide(); }";
}).GetHtml()
```

I am trying to get the text that is typed into this box on the server side (in the action on my controller).  In other places in my application I have been able to use the following code to get values of controls:

```
public ActionResult ResolveReview(bool Pass)
{ ...
EditorExtension.GetValue<string>("txtReviewComment")
...}
```

However this returns null in this scenario.  What is the correct way to get this value from a control in a partial view rendered in a popupcontrol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on my own, my button was causing a GET method to fire instead of POST.  By setting "UseSubmitBehavior" to true on my save button, it started firing the POST function and allowing the
    `EditorExtension.GetValue<string>("txtReviewComment")`

line to get a value.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is necessary to wrap editors within a form container in order to pass the entire form's content on submit. Then, it is possible to retrive the required editor's value using the **standard Model Binding** mechanism. When using DevExpress MVC Editors, make sure that the **DevExpressEditorsBinder** is registered:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ResolveReview")) {
    @Html.DevExpress().Memo(settings => {
        settings.Name = "txtReviewComment";
    }).GetHtml()

    @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings => {
        settings.Name = "btnSaveReview";
        settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
    }).GetHtml()
}

public ActionResult ResolveReview(bool Pass) {
    EditorExtension.GetValue<string>("txtReviewComment")
}
```

or

```
public ActionResult ResolveReview(string txtReviewComment) { ... }
```

Check the [MVC Data Editors - Model Binding and Editing](https://www.devexpress.com/kbid=KA18701) learning resource.